# Is mobx(5*) + mobx-react (6*) versions are compatable for react 18 version

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

[From mobx-react official doc](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/tree/main/packages/mobx-react#mobx-react) resource as a guide. We concluded that mobx(5*) + mobx-react (6*) versions are compatible for react 18 version. But after updating our repo we got some issues related to [React 18: observer not working with React Class components <React.StrictMode>](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/3395)

Our Versions

```
"mobx": "5.15.0",
"mobx-react": "6.1.4",
"react": "18.2.0",
```

Are mobx(5*) and mobx-react(6*) versions compatible with react 18?
If not, What are the compatible versions of mobx and mobx-react that can be used when using React 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We concluded that mobx(5*) + mobx-react (6*) versions are compatible for react 18 version.

How you made this conclusion? It clearly says that `mobx-react` v6 only supports `>16.8 <18` React, and `<18` means that React version 18 is not supported.

| NPM Version | Support MobX version | Supported React versions | Supports hook based components |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| v7 | 6.* | >16.8 | Yes |
| v6 | 4.* / 5.* | >16.8 <18 | Yes |
| v5 | 4.* / 5.* | >0.13 <18 | No, but it is possible to use `<Observer>` sections inside hook based components |

So your only option is `mobx-react@7` and `mobx@6`.

EDIT: Oh, I see that matrix was just [updated](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/commit/7306793d363fd4de137bccb71d2fd23ac25dd20d) because you also asked this question on Github Discussions, and before it stated different information, so it's not your fault at all, sorry.